# accessing a file

Tags: c, linux, file-io

On Linux, how can I make sure that my program is the only one accessing a file?

Comment: This is platform dependent. What operating system are you writing this for?

Comment: you can compile on pretty much every modern architecture and operating system using gcc, so it doesn't tell you much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, but I believe you are referring to [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking). See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) and [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/flockfile) and don't forget [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl). Your display name is gcc but if you are doing this on windows, see [LockFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365203.aspx).

Comment: dunno, but it seems perfectly reasonable to me.